# creating a class: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)?

Tags: ruby, class

I am getting stack level too deep (SystemStackError) when I run `ruby lib/interface.rb` and I dont understand why this is happening.

This is my **car.rb** file:

```
class Car
  def initialize(color, year, second_hand)
    @color = color
    @year = year
    @second_hand = second_hand
  end

  def color
    return color
  end

  def year
    return year
  end

  def second_hand?
    return second_hand
  end
end
```

and this is my **interface.rb**:

```
require_relative "car"

my_car = Car.new("red", "1988", false)
puts my_car.color
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
def color
  return color
end
```

This calls the `color` method in an endless loop. Try

```
def color
  return @color
end
```

Same for `year`, etc.

Comment: Thanks @steenslag. I understand know why this endless loop.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland I thought the same thing, but adding  `attr_reader :color` or `attr_accessor :color` I still get an error message:  undefined method `attr_reader' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Comment: Juan, the error message’s reference to `main` identifies the problem. You need to execute `attr_reader :color` when `self  #=> Car`: `class Car;  attr_reader :color; end`.